# Define "no color" in a table cell

Tags: tables, color

Is is possible to define a colour as no colour? This is for use in LaTeX tables for individual cells to override a defined `\rowcolor`.

I've experimented with using a white colour, but then if the user prints on coloured paper this wouldn't work (e.g. `\definecolor{White}{rgb}{1,1,1}`). Another thought has been full transparency, but not all PDF viewers/prints handle transparent colours.

Thanks,
FE

Comment: A defined `\rowcolor` can be overridden with `\cellcolor`.

Comment: Providing an MWE might be helpful here.

Comment: Great comment on a 2 year old question. Standing ovation for this guy over here.

Comment: For most printing technologies used to print on paper, white will just work fine, regardless of the paper colour, because white will just mean that no colour is applied.